# Debugging with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm stuck debugging a custom loss function in KERAS. My problem is at one point there is a division by 0 and some values become NaN which propagates to the loss function. 
But the reason for 0 appearing in the denominator for me is not obvious. What I would like to see is a dump of y_true and y_pred which result in division by zero. Can I get these values somehow? Like tf.Print but dumping it to file or something similar.

```
def yolo_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    grid_shape = np.array([7, 7]) # TODO: detect automatically
    anchors_size = 2 # TODO: detect automatically

    pred_box = tf.stack(tf.split(y_pred[..., 0:anchors_size * 5], num_or_size_splits=anchors_size, axis=3), axis=3)
    true_box = tf.stack(tf.split(y_true[..., 0:anchors_size * 5], num_or_size_splits=anchors_size, axis=3), axis=3)

    pred_box_xy = pred_box[..., 0:2]
    pred_box_wh = pred_box[..., 2:4]
    pred_box_conf = pred_box[..., 4:5]  # tf.sigmoid(
    pred_class = y_pred[..., (anchors_size * 5):]

    true_box_xy = true_box[..., 0:2]
    true_box_wh = true_box[..., 2:4]
    true_box_mask = true_box[..., 4:5]  # tf.sigmoid(
    true_class = y_true[..., (anchors_size * 5):]

    #################################
    ### adjust confidence using IoU
    #################################
    true_wh_half = true_box_wh**2 * grid_shape / 2.
    true_mins = true_box_xy - true_wh_half
    true_maxes = true_box_xy + true_wh_half

    pred_wh_half = pred_box_wh**2 * grid_shape / 2.
    pred_mins = pred_box_xy - pred_wh_half
    pred_maxes = pred_box_xy + pred_wh_half

    intersect_mins = tf.maximum(pred_mins, true_mins)
    intersect_maxes = tf.minimum(pred_maxes, true_maxes)
    intersect_wh = tf.maximum(intersect_maxes - intersect_mins, 0.)
    intersect_areas = intersect_wh[..., 0] * intersect_wh[..., 1]

    true_areas = (true_box_wh[..., 0] * true_box_wh[..., 1])**2
    pred_areas = (pred_box_wh[..., 0] * pred_box_wh[..., 1])**2

    union_areas = pred_areas + true_areas - intersect_areas + 1e-6
    iou_scores = tf.truediv(intersect_areas, union_areas)

    true_box_conf = tf.expand_dims(iou_scores, 4) * true_box_mask

    obj_threshold = 0.6
    true_box_obj = tf.to_float(true_box_mask >= obj_threshold)
    true_box_noobj = tf.to_float(true_box_mask < obj_threshold)
    true_cell_obj = tf.reduce_max(true_box_obj, reduction_indices=[3, 4])
    loss_xy = true_box_obj * tf.squared_difference(pred_box_xy, true_box_xy)
    loss_xy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(loss_xy, reduction_indices=(1, 2, 3, 4)))
    loss_wh = true_box_obj * tf.squared_difference(pred_box_wh, true_box_wh)
    loss_wh = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(loss_wh, reduction_indices=(1, 2, 3, 4)))

    loss_conf = true_box_obj * tf.squared_difference(pred_box_conf, true_box_conf)
    loss_conf = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(loss_conf, reduction_indices=(1, 2, 3, 4)))

    loss_notconf = true_box_noobj * tf.squared_difference(pred_box_conf, true_box_conf)
    loss_notconf = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(loss_notconf, reduction_indices=(1, 2, 3, 4)))
    loss_class = tf.squared_difference(pred_class, true_class)
    loss_class = true_cell_obj * tf.reduce_sum(loss_class, reduction_indices=(3))
    loss_class = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(loss_class, reduction_indices=(1, 2)))

    loss = 5. * loss_xy + 5. * loss_wh + loss_conf + 0.5 * loss_notconf + loss_class
    return loss
```

Comment: What does the loss functions' code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could grep the output of `tf.Print` and directed to a file.

Alternatively you could just extract the tensor values by passing it to the `session.run` method. Then you could dump it to a file yourself. I don't think TensorFlow has that functionality built in.

Another alternative would be to use a summary tensor. The plain types are a bit limited. You could use a string summary tensor but that may not be much better than the output of tf.Print.

TensorFlow offers more operation similar `tf.Print`: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/control_flow_ops#Debugging_Operations

You might find [tf.is_nan](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/is_nan) or [tf.Assert](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Assert) useful.

Comment: Well, that is basically what I ended up doing. Using tf.Print to print data then import it using numpy into my Jupiter notebook and debugging particular run of loss function from there. This is not the most convenient way but it is better than blindly searching for mistakes